# VS 2022 Metadata file 'C:\*\crypto.dll' could not be found when a project .NET 6.0 reference a submodule project .netstandard2.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, .net-standard-2.0

I know there are some questions with the same problem, I went through all the answers, and none helped me.

I have a MSTest project .NET 6.0, everything went fine until I added a reference to a project in sub repo (it is added as submodule in my project). The submodule project use .netstandard2.0.

The first time I cleaned and built the solution, I got the error NU1105 as below:

```
NU1105 Unable to find project information for <the submodule project>.\.csproj. If you are using Visual Studio, this may be because the project is unloaded or not part of current solution so run a restore from the command-line. Otherwise, the project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore.
```

I run dotnet restore using Package Manager Console. Then I got error CS0006:

```
Error CS0006 Metadata file 'C:\*\<the submodule project>.dll' could not be found
```

Cleaning and building didn't work. Unloading the project didn't work. Restarting Visual Studio didn't work.

Does anyone has the same problem and find solution? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your solution file? Can you also try closing the visual studio then deleting the  .vs folder and reopening visual studio again?

Comment: Thanks @vivek nuna for your reply. I closed VS, deleted the .vs folder and reopen VS but the error still shown up

Comment: Post your solution file in the question

Answer (score 1):

We found the solution. After we run "msbuild dirs.proj /restore" in Developer Powershell window then it works. Thanks!