# How to remove an analyzer assembly from a project in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, analyzer

I was trying to add a reference assembly to my project but instead I added it as an analyzer assembly by mistake. After deleting the folder containing that assembly, I am no longer able to build the project due to the error shown below:
[image]

I was trying to remove the assembly but there is nothing shown under the analyzers in the solution explorer. Any idea how I can do that? or at least change the file path such that it can locate it in its new directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CS0006 failed to find the metadata file, which is a common error message that may be encountered during C# programming. This error message usually means that the compiler cannot find the assembly's metadata file, causing compilation to fail.

Here are three recommended solutions:

1. Build => Clean Solution
2. Open the csproj file of your project with Notepad, find the dll path you misreferenced, delete the ItemGroup, and reopen the project
3. I found a similar post: [VS 2022 Metadata file 'C:*\crypto.dll' could not be found when a project .NET 6.0 reference a submodule project .netstandard2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74453518/vs-2022-metadata-file-c-crypto-dll-could-not-be-found-when-a-project-net-6), his approach is to use powershell to execute "msbuild dirs. proj /restore"

If it doesn't work can you share how you added the assembly as analyzer assembly

Comment: Worked like a charm! I wish I got your answer yesterday before deciding to use a one week old backup and copy all the code from the new one to the backup. It is not a very big project so It wasn't that bad after all. But now I have this answer for future reference. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The 1st solution is find the Portable.BouncyCastle.dll package remove and insert it again.

You can find it here:
[Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPO4b.png)

Or you can remove the assembly of that package or analyser. See image:
[Assemblies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQAuH.png)